# Tutorial information bubble control on iOS

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.ios, uibubbletableview

Is there a control on iOS or a well known library that offers info bubble functionality. (I am relatively new to iOS development so I am not sure if my search keywords are off or this is just not being used on iOS very much)

I would like to achieve something like this:

[image][image]

This comes from [Android Tutorial Bubbles library](https://github.com/lovoo/android-tutorial-bubbles).

I would like to avoid building this control by myself if there is already similar library or something that is being more widely used on iOS.

I found something similar called ["ProductTour"](https://github.com/Cclleemm/ProductTour) but it seems to be quite limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use PopOverPresentation style/segue to achieve this effect. But you have to customize.

I just customize just a little and here is the output.
[image]

Comment: you can use this too. you know library is always handy. https://github.com/teodorpatras/EasyTipView